# Wordpress without htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm currently setting up a wordpress site and the links are `URL/about/`
How does that work if there is no htaccess file?

I was under the impression you always needed a htaccess to do that sort of stuff, but there is none, so there must be another way? I do have hidden files showing so I know it's not just hidden

Comment: Wordpress attemps to create .htaccess file from the backend, when you enable friendly URLs, or, if it can't write the .htaccess file, it generates the output and asks you to create the file using it. Also there is a default .htaccess file here https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Comment: The site works fine and there is no htaccess file, I'm asking how this is possible

Comment: Sounds impossible to me, are you sure that you enabled show hidden files option? Also, are you sure that there are no .htaccess files in parent directories?

Comment: Yeah definitely have hidden files enabled, can see others, there is no htaccess file in the parent directory that I have access to

Comment: I can't think on any other thing but cache. Unless your server silently redirects all 404 to your WP index.php file

Comment: I can get other 404 errors, so it's not that. Wordpress has never said it failed to create a htaccess file or needs one so I'm assuming that it must be working fine, I'm just not sure what it's doing

Comment: can you run this code in your website's root directory (create file, let's say qcheck.php): `<?php echo file_get_contents('.htaccess'); ?>` and see what happens after you access it using your web browser?

Comment: There is a blank page, nothing in the source code either

Comment: Setting up WordPress with Custom Permalinks and no .htaccess File
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/994/setting-up-wordpress-with-custom-permalinks-and-no-htaccess-file